# Ember complains about undefined namespace

Tags: ember.js

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You are looking for a edit controller in the Node namespace, but the namespace could not be found
```

But if I inspect the objects (Chrome developer tools), I confirm that:

- `App.NodeEditController` is defined
- `Ember.TEMPLATES['node/edit']` is defined (I am using pre-compiled templates)
- The model `App.Node` is defined

What could be causing this problem? What else could I verify? What is this [namespace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Namespace.html) thing? I have not used it before, and my application was working.

The only changes I have performed are related to reorganization of my code base: I have split templates/controllers/models/views into files - but they are concatenatted again with a `grunt` task, so that no real changes should be present (appart from the fact that I am using now pre-compiled templates)

I have also verified `SettingsApp.Router.router.recognizer.names`:

[image: router names]

Comment: Could you strip this down to a small example that still fails, and (if you like) post it somewhere like jsFiddle? I suspect the real problem may be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The error reads as if the EditController is defined as `Node.EditController` or `App.Node.EditController`. So you need to show more code, if this is not the case.

Comment: @gonvaled, you can verify what ember knows about your routes by doing App.Router.router.recognizer.names with your app started from the chrome dev tools, hope it helps

Comment: regarding the namespace, a namespace is mostly useful in the case when there are multiple ember app within a single webpage. Ember needs the templates to live in the "Ember" namespace not in your app's namespace "App". making the compiled template code available under the Ember namespace would fix the problem I think, but maybe there is more to it

Comment: I have created a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ifigup/5/edit. All my templates/controllers/models/... are there. I also had to embed ember-data, since the CDN version does not play well with the CDN version of ember (ember-data is still unstable). Unfortunately, I have no local data (in my application, it is obtained via REST), so you can actually not click on the "node edit" action, which is the one that is failing. But at least you can see all my code. The templates are pre-compiled, I hope that is not a problem. Also, no CSS, so it's ugly.

Comment: @mokane: routes added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solves the problem, at least you can navigate to the edit route again

change this:

```
SettingsApp.NodeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    needs: [node/edit]
    ...
```

to this (remove the needs)

```
SettingsApp.NodeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
isEditing: false
...
```

hope it helps ...